# Class not found in chained namespaces

Tags: windows, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

I've installed a small app done with ZendFramework and Doctrine 2, in a Windows Server running IIS.

The app, runs fine under linux, but in my windows machine, i get the following error:

```
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.

Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:38
The class '' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Common\Entity
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain.php(114): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces(false, Array)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php(113): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass(false, Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(302): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array)
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(205): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('App\Common\Enti...')
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(268): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('App\Common\Enti...')
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(682): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('App\Common\Enti...')
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\modules\App\Main\src\App\Main\Controller\IndexController.php(24): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('App\Common\Enti...')
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): App\Main\Controller\IndexController->indexAction()
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php(25): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

The weird part is that, in the error.. the class name is empty.
What might be??

**-- UPDATE**

So, this is what i call

`$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Common\Entity\Setting');`

And my entity:

```
namespace App\Common\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Common\Model\Repository\Settings")
 * @ORM\Table(name="settings")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Setting {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false);
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Etc\App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $author;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(\Etc\App\Entity\User $author) {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

}
```

**-- UPDATE 2**

```
namespace App\Common\Model\Repository;

class Settings {

    public function findAllFlatten() {
        // nothing relevant here.. 
    }

}



namespace Etc\App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Etc\App\Model\Repository\User")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false);
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=48, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $password;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

}
```

Comment: usually this kind of error has to do with you using the "\" at the beginning of the classes or namespaces, when you shouldent, or not using it where you should. If your paste the code of the implied classes i can chek it out

Comment: also, put the code of `App\Common\Model\Repository\Settings` and `\Etc\App\Entity\User` are those classes accesible? are they namespaces correctly set? I would say that it is a problem with the repository

Comment: @CarlosRobles new update. my repos have nothing in special.. just one or two simple findby wrapper..

Comment: yeah, nothing special here. the only thing  can see is that your repository is not extending anything. it should be `namespace App\Common\Model\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
 

class Settings extends EntityRepository { ... `

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks normal, but the only thing can see is that your repository is not extending anything. it should extend the doctrine repository class:

```
<? 
   namespace App\Common\Model\Repository; 

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; 

   class Settings extends EntityRepository { 
       /// ... 

   }
```

Also, do you have configured all the namespaces? remember that in the configuration files, you have the doctrine config, such as:

```
'doctrine' => array (
                'driver' => array (
                        'mi_driver' => array (
                                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                                'cache' => 'array',
                                'paths' => array (
                                        __DIR__ . '/PATH_TO_CLASS_FILES' 
                                ) 
                        ),


                        'orm_default' => array (
                                'drivers' => array (
                                        "NAMESPACE"=>"mi_driver", "NAMESPACE2"=>"mi_driver",

                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);
```

And also, check if the autoloader is correctly configured. try it just creating an instance of the classes anywhere in your code `new App\Common\Entity\Setting()`

Comment: It is, it was just an edit typo, and i've deleted by mistake that part.. anyways, could this be a server problem? and if so, what might be? this is really strange..

Comment: @MGP could you take a look at my last update? did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but in my case the problem was composers class cache. I had to execute

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to solve this problem.